# Label move afterwards

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

In my Perforce workspace was one file `squirtle.txt`. In Windows Explorer, I renamed it to `blastoise.txt` and made some changes to it in Notepad . In P4V I ran reconcile offline work, now in my changelist I have file `squirtle.txt` marked as 'deleted' and `blastoise.txt` marked as 'add'.

I've heard it's best to inform Perforce that `blastoise.txt` evolved from  `squirtle.txt`, so that if blastoise is inspected, squirtles history will be listed beneath. How do I inform Perforce about the move?

That was an example. In my actual case I've moved tens of files, both renaming them and moving folder.

---

**Edit**: I'm told that I should never had dared rename files in Windows Explorer but instead done so with a special Perforce command [`p4 move`](http://kb.perforce.com/article/7/renaming-files). Never mind what I should have done, what do I now with my situation as it stands?

Is there a `p4 moved squirtle.txt blastoise.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In P4V, go to the Pending tab on the right of the screen and select the squirtle.txt and blastoise.txt from your default changelist, then right click and select Revert to back out the change you did outside P4V.

Still in P4V, select squirtle.txt in the depot tree and right click, then select "Rename / Move ..." to rename it.

Comment: Thanks I made a copy of my `blastoise.txt`, then followed your instructions, then restored my `blastoise.txt` to keep my changes.